# Setting a form's initial values via a change in parent component props, and also via useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a Formik form which is being used to edit existing data, which is retrieved from a database.  The existing data is passed to the `MembersCommentsEdit` function below via props from a parent component.  One of the form fields, `existing_member_comments`, contains a list of existing comments.  The field `member_comments` then allows a user to add another comment to the database.

I'm initially populating these Formik fields using the Formik `initialValues` prop - initially setting this to contain data retrieved from the props of the `MembersCommentsEdit` function.

When the user adds a new comment and hits submit, it is saved to the database OK, but I also want to add that comment to the list of existing comments in the `existing_member_comments` field.

I've achieved this by making `initialValues` a state variable (rather than a `const` variable as I had originally coded), initially populating it with data from the `existing_member_comments` props, then changing its contents using the `setInitialValues` function from within the Formik form's `onSubmit/onSuccess` function, when the user submits the form.

This approach successfully updates the `initialValues` after form submission, but causes an issue: if the props being passed to the `MembersCommentsEdit` function from its parent component change at any point (a change would be triggered by a user in the parent component), then the `initialValues` should change to reflect those new props. This happened OK when `initialValues` was just a simple `const` variable, but not now it is a state variable.

This is the code:

```
function MembersCommentsEdit(props) {
  const { mutate } = useMembersCommentsCreateMutation();

  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({
    forename: props?.membersCommentsData?.[0].forename ?? '',
    surname: props?.membersCommentsData?.[0].surname ?? '',
    address_1: props?.membersCommentsData?.[0].address_1 ?? '',
    last_updated_by: userNameConcatenated,
    member_id: props?.membersCommentsData?.[0].member_id ?? '',
    existing_member_comments: joinedArray,
  });
  return (
   <Formik
      enableReinitialize={true}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={(values, formik) => {
```

```
        mutate(values, {
          onSuccess: () => {
            setOpen(true);
            setMessage('Member comment saved!');
            setSeverity('success');
            setButtonIsClicked(buttonisClicked + 1); 
             setInitialValues((prevValues) => ({
              ...prevValues,
              existing_member_comments:
                'Created On: ' +
                today +
                '\n' +
                'Added by: ' +
                values.last_updated_by +
                '\n' +
                'Comment: ' +
                values.member_comment +
                '\n \n' +
                values.existing_member_comments
            }));

            formik.resetForm();
```

To overcome the problem described above, I then tried adding a `useEffect` hook to listen for prop changes on `MembersCommentsEdit`, which worked in as far as changes to the props resulted in changes in the `initialValues` state again.  But, for some reason, it prevented the `setInitialValues` solution from updating the state.

Code below, which I put directly beneath the `initialValues` state block of code above.

```
       useEffect(() => {
            setInitialValues({
              forename: props?.membersCommentsData?.[0].forename ?? '',
              surname: props?.membersCommentsData?.[0].surname ?? '',
              address_1: props?.membersCommentsData?.[0].address_1 ?? '',
              last_updated_by: userNameConcatenated,
              member_id: props?.membersCommentsData?.[0].member_id ?? '',
              existing_member_comments: joinedArray,
            });
          }, [props]);
```

Can anyone explain for me why this issue is occurring and how I might get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went a different route and used Formik's `formik.setFieldValue` prop to set the value in the existing_member_comments field, rather than trying to update it via Formik's `initialValues` prop.  So `initialValues` was set back to being a simple `const`, then the `onSubmit` function adjusted as follows:

```
      onSubmit={(values, formik) => {
        console.log('values=', values);
        mutate(values, {
          onSuccess: () => {
            setOpen(true);
            setMessage('Member comment saved!');
            setSeverity('success');
            setButtonIsClicked(buttonisClicked + 1); //updates Recoil global state, to trigger data-table refetch of data

            formik.setFieldValue('existing_member_comments', 
                'Created On: ' +
                today +
                '\n' +
                'Added by: ' +
                values.last_updated_by +
                '\n' +
                'Comment: ' +
                values.member_comment +
                '\n \n' +
                values.existing_member_comments)
            
                formik.setFieldValue('member_comment', '')

          },
```